# Why checkStartAndEnd is not found in Android java.util.Arrays?

Tags: android

I look at Android source code

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/cff1616/luni/src/main/java/java/util/Arrays.java#1742

I realize Android's `Arrays` contains a public static method named `checkStartAndEnd`, which is not found in Java standard SE.

However, when I type `java.util.Arrays.checkStartAndEnd` in Android Studio, or look at the documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Arrays.html, I realize `checkStartAndEnd` isn't valid for Android's `Arrays` class.

May I know why is it so? Am I looking at wrong Android source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot see / use it because it's hidden (check the `@hide` tag in the Javadoc). If you compare the Android `Arrays` class with the Java SE one, you'll see that this `checkStartAndEnd` basically equals to `rangeCheck`, which is a `private` method there as well. As to why did they rename it? I have no idea, maybe some licensing issue or something else.

Comment: I think it was when Oracle tried to sue Google over Android Java usage. It was a rangecheck function, see https://developers.slashdot.org/story/12/05/16/1612228/judge-to-oracle-a-high-schooler-could-write-rangecheck

Comment: Btw, I enjoy using your preference library. It is a great library :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help.